# Django runserver error: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, django, server

I'm running a local dev project made with Django. But I cannot have the dev server to start:

```
(Gaia_database_env)FakeComputer:gaia_database_proj FakeUser$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinymce/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tinymce import widgets as tinymce_widgets
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinymce/widgets.py", line 10, in <module>
    import tinymce.settings
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/tinymce/settings.py", line 16, in <module>
    JS_ROOT = getattr(settings, 'TINYMCE_JS_ROOT',os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'tiny_mce'))
  File "/Users/FakeUser/GoogleDrive/Sites/Gaia_database_env/bin/../lib/python3.4/posixpath.py", line 82, in join
    path += b
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'NoneType' and 'str
```

I'm working into a virtual env with this packages:

```
(Gaia_database_env)FakeComputer:gaia_database_proj FakeUser$ pip freeze
Django==1.8.2
django-bootstrap3==6.1.0
django-tinymce==1.5.3
wheel==0.24.0
```

And that's my settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'm6eu#pf_u$upk2qkizhp%gvc6wb%1(alhey8!hqkdzq%j%b4&('

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'tinymce',
    'bootstrap3',
    'gaia_app'
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gaia_database.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gaia_database.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'CET'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Any idea??

Thanks

Comment: @nu11p01n73R Dude, if you just read the exception you can see that he's calling os.path.join. I don't think telling him path += b is failing is going to help unless he want to rewrite the os.path.join function.

Comment: @Bakaburg, is tinymce an app you're developing or something someone made and you're trying to use? We probably need to see the tinymce/settings.py file.

Comment: So the problem is not in posixpath.py! TinyMCE it's a pretty common html5 based rich text editor. What should I look for into settings.py?

Comment: Preferably just post it so we can see it. It looks like settings.STATIC_ROOT is None, which I would guess means that settings isn't getting loaded properly.

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 1.7, `STATIC_ROOT` defaults to `None`, so unless you've set it, TinyMCE will be unable to properly serve its JS files.

You should either:

- Set `TINYMCE_JS_ROOT`
- Set `STATIC_ROOT`

Now, those settings aren't going to be used unless you also set `TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR` to `True` (it defaults to `False`), so if you don't know what they are, I'd recommend you set `TINYMCE_JS_ROOT` to `"tiny_mce"` for now.

---

The [TinyMCE documentation](http://django-tinymce.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/.build/html/installation.html#configuration) has some information on configuration, but it's neither very accurate or helpful. The [actual code that runs](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-tinymce/blob/494b3674555f681b90a338eeb9b59901499cc322/tinymce/settings.py) is here, and [here is where `JS_ROOT` is actually used](https://github.com/gregmuellegger/django-tinymce/blob/494b3674555f681b90a338eeb9b59901499cc322/tinymce/compressor.py).

Comment: uhm... I added TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = "tiny_mce" to my settings and nothing changed. I also wrote my settings in my questions. I suppose instead of just write down the path to tiny_mce. But it's in the virtual env python folder. I don't think I should declare the full absolute path to that folder...